# Code doesn't have a problem but it doesn't work either

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code doesn't have any errors but it doesn't work:

```
import  random 
for n in 'karlson' : 
x = random.random()
```

I think the problem is the random code but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: Is the `x = random.random()` line indented? Python is extremely picky about indentation.

Comment: you cannot have an empty for loop as you have.

Comment: If this is run from an interactive console, like IDLE or Jupyter notebook, you don't need print. But if it is run from a file (`code.py`), then please add `print(x)` to see the output

Comment: You should add what you're expecting from that code. If we don't know the output you need, we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you want to do. I'll tell you exactly what your code does, hoping that helps you:

```
import random
```

well that's an import nothing to say

```
for n in 'karlson':
x = random.random()
```

The for loop is empty because the line after ":" isn't tabbed, so the script will raise an `IndentationError` and stop execution.
Let's assume you wrote:

```
for n in 'karlson':
    x = random.random()
```

the for loop will read the str 'karlson' letter by letter and will assign a random float between 0.0 and 1.0 to the variable x every iteration.
Then it stops. You have no output.

Comment: An empty `for` loop will raise an `IndentationError` and stop execution. Not do nothing.